# Reactjs - Obtain selected value of mapped array in dropdown <option>

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I have a dropdown select option that maps the data of a given array object 'template_titles'. Currently the value is set to the title in the array object. I want to be able to use the selected value from the dropdown. How would I get that selected value?

demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/sleepy-tdd-i58lb?file=/src/App.jsx

```
const tester = () => {
    const data = template_titles.find((e) => (e = 'I WANT THIS VALUE HERE'));
    console.log(data);
    setSubject(data.subject);
    setText(data.text);
    setCC(data.cc);
    setBCC(data.bcc);
};

    <div className='row wrapper'>
            <label className='template'>Template</label>
            <select
                className='template-input'
                id='template-select'
                onChange={tester}
            >
                <option>---</option>
                {template_titles.map((option) => (
                    <option
                        key={option.id}
                        value={option.title}
                        onChange={(e) => setTemplate(e.target.value)}
                    >
                        {option.title}
                    </option>
                ))}
            </select>
        </div>
```

Comment: What is `tester` here? Post that function code also..

Comment: Just edited. The tester function: given the value, changes specifc input values in my list. I am attempting to recreate an autofill function.

Comment: I am not sure how are you able to call this function without using `this.tester`. Please create a [small demo](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for this using [codesandbox.io](https://codesandbox.io/s/new) once.

Comment: Sorry would this is currently running in a function component not a class component. Will work on a demo

Comment: edited with demo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the selected value from the dropdown `template-select` by passing the [event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event) object as `e` to the `tester` function like:

```
const tester = (e) => {
    console.log(e.target.value);
    //.... your code here

    // You can then also search `template_titles` array like
    const data = template_titles.find(el => el === e.target.value);
    console.log(data);
};
```

Here `e.target.value` is the selected option value.

Please also know that right now using `data.subject` or any call to other property on `data` will return `undefined`, as `template_titles` is a simple string array in the demo like:

```
template_titles = ["hello", "hi", "hi"];
```

`data.subject` will only work when `template_titles` data will be replaced with an array of objects.

For more info:

- [Handling Events](https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html)
- [Event.target](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/target)

Comment: for data.sugest, in the demo I understand it will return undefined. In my actualy project I used an object with values subject, text, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend using React Select in place of native selects. Check it out https://react-select.com/home. It has a bunch of built in extras like multi select and even loading it's options asynchronously. It also lets users type into it to narrow down the options it displays, which I think it is what you're after.

It takes an array of options as a prop that looks like `[{value: 'option-value', label: 'Option Value Shown To User'}]`.

It also takes an `onChange` which (for a single select) provides the option the user picked so your change handler can look like:

```
handleSelectChange(({ value }) => { /*whatever you want to do with the value*/ })
```